# Excerpt filter does not cut the excerpt

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to shorten the excerpt but it does not work. It shows the full excerpt which I write in the post edit!

I've added this to the functions.php

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Even if I delete the above code it does not show default 55 words. I reviewed all my files and I can't find the problem.

To show the excerpt I'm using:

`if(has_excerpt() { the_excerpt(); } else { the_content(); }`

Where can be the problem? Any ideas what can cause this?

Comment: Asking in http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ might be more appropriate

Comment: Oh thanks, didn't knew about this.